# Is there any way to zoom in on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Feel a little silly asking this here, but any web results only returned issues related to G Calendar and the Zoom video call software.

I schedule many tasks in hour slots and with Google Calendar's default zoom, I can't see them properly. Is there any way to zoom in on time slots? Seems like an obvious user feature but I'm stumped.

TIA

Comment: using Google Calendar in Firefox (ubuntu) pressing `Ctrl+` zooms in and `Ctrl-` zooms out.

Comment: Good question, I was wondering too. Of course, I believe you're asking for vertical zoom, which the browser can't provide (Ctrl +/- will zoom on both axes).

Comment: I think you can only do that on mobile

Comment: You could probably write some custom CSS using an extension like Stylus. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne